# How do I validate if a list in my model has at least one element?

Tags: angularjs

In my Angular 1.6 code, I have something like this:

```
<div class="house" ng-repeat="house in $ctrl.houses" ng-form="houseForm">
  <div class="room" ng-repeat="room in house.rooms" ng-form="roomForm">
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in room.items" ng-form="itemForm">
      <input ng-repeat="question in item.questions" ng-required="true" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I then use the ng-invalid CSS classes then to style the invalid inputs and the invalid sections. Now I have a new requirement where I need to consider a segment without elements (e.g. a room without items) as invalid and give it the same styling as if it were to contain an invalid input.

I tried to hack it using a hidden input like so

```
<input type="number" disabled ng-model="room.Items.length" ng-required="true" min="1" style="display:none"/>
```

which worked, but gave me a Javascript error on page-load. It is also not very clean. What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from Immanuel Kirubaharan S was close, but didn't work in all scenarios. This small modification does work.

```
<div class="house" ng-repeat="house in $ctrl.houses" ng-form="houseForm">
  <div class="room" ng-repeat="room in house.rooms" ng-form="roomForm">
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in room.items" ng-form="itemForm">
      <input ng-repeat="question in item.questions" ng-required="true" />
    </div>
    <div class="item" ng-if="!room.items">
      <input ng-model="room.Items[0]" ng-required="true" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like the below code?

```
<div class="house" ng-repeat="house in $ctrl.houses" ng-form="houseForm">
  <div class="room" ng-repeat="room in house.rooms" ng-form="roomForm">
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in room.items" ng-form="itemForm">
      <input ng-repeat="question in item.questions" ng-required="true" />
    </div>
    <div class="item" ng-if="!room.items">
      <input ng-model="room.Items" minlength="1" ng-required="true" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried this, and it works until I remove all elements and then try to add a new one. Then the input remains empty and invalid.